# Towers of Hanoi with Stack but without any recursion

Tags: java

I already got the Towers of Hanoi with recursion, it's also working without any problems. But now I'd like to know how it could work without recursion but with stack instead.

```
public class Hanoirecursive {

  static void move (
    int x,
    char start,
    char help,
    char aim) {

    if (x == 1)
        System.out.println("  from " + start + " to " + aim);

    else {
        move(x-1,start, aim, help);
        System.out.println("  from " + start + " to " + aim);
        move(x-1,help, start, aim);
    }
  }

  public static void main (String args[]) {

    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    if (x > 0) {
      System.out.println("Movements: ");
      move(x,'A','B','C');
    }
    else
      System.out.println("No negative number.");
  }
}
```

I would like to.. convert this code so it works with a stack and no longer with recursion but I really don't know where to start. Could you give me some hints please?

For the stack I could find this on the internet:

```
public class Stack {
private int[] stackElements;
private int top;

public Stack(int a) {
stackElements = new int[a];
top = -1;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
return top == -1;
}

public void push(int b) {
stackElements[++top] = b;
}

public int pop() {
if(isEmpty() ) {
System.out.println( "Empty stack" );
return -1;
}
else {
return stackElements[top--];
}
}
}
```

Any kind of help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I'm not looking for someone who is going to solve the entire task, as stated in topic description I'm looking for some hints, where to start for example.

Comment: @azurefrog it's a much a question as your question.

Comment: @nicomp My question is self-answered, and I wrote it so that I could use it as a target for flagging duplicates.  If you have any suggestions to make it more clear please let me know and I will improve it.

Comment: @nakuta Please take another look at the meta article I linked.  The point is that "can you give me some hints re: tower of hanoi?" is not very likely to be useful to other people.  A better question would be "how do I convert a recursive program to an iterative one?", using your program as a concrete example.

Comment: In any case, take a look at [Ways to go from recursion to iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration) for some general ideas on converting your program.